# nautilus automount devices

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

When opening Nautilus it shows my `Devices` (which are actually just other partitions) like this:

[image]

However, they are not mounted. When I now click them, they get mounted.

What do I have to do to have them mounted automatically?

Comment: Note to reviewers: OP replies to question posed as an answer below that they want `/dev/sdb2`, `ntfs` automounted at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ubuntu are you using? For 12.10, I know the devices (eg pendrives, modems) are mounted by default when inserted when the computer is already on. But for a device such as a hard disk (or partition), it doesn't mount when you start the computer. You have to do that manually. I see that to be a security feature in Linux to prevent unwanted mounting of devices.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, it is 12.04 LTS. My question is how I can automount it? (`/dev/sdb2`, `ntfs`)